# Dope Sheet Proportional Edit falloff types?

Tags: dopesheet

just wondering if the falloff types are working for proportional editing in the Dope Sheet. All the falloff types seem to be doing the same thing.

I want to play around with taking a batch of keyframes and doing various stretching and squashing of them using various falloff types, including random falloff.

I select the first keyframe in the Dope Sheet, turn on proportional edit, then S for scale and drag mouse right a bit, and I see the stretching out of the remaining keyframes, but all the falloffs seem to produce the same kind of stretching results.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Looks like they work correctly if you **Grab** them around, but **not for the Scaling** (there's not even any reference about the proportional size in the operator string showing the current parameters).